# What would an ancient Greek village (small settlement) have looked like?

Tags: ancient-greece, social-history

Context: I am preparing a D&D campaign, and because I find "medieval western europe fantasy land" to be a bit over-used, I'd like to make my setting more of an ancient greek setting.

However, there are a lot less resources surrounding this culture. One question I have in particular is how would a small village (100-500 people) be organised? What kind of activities would the villagers get up to most of the day? What did their architecture look like? Who ruled them?

There are plenty of big cities that were preserved and studied quite well, but I'm struggling to find information concerning what life was like for regular Iosif out in rural Greece...

Comment: What research have you done? What is wrong with [existing resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=ancient+greek+village&newwindow=1&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS573US573&sxsrf=ACYBGNRfMOB762dJ5zukgDaOscFs5LCoug:1579195386274&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7iJ6g0YjnAhUBzlkKHUBvDmYQ_AUoAXoECCMQAw&biw=1920&bih=979)?

Comment: There is many different Greek cultures placed under "Ancient Greece". Could you be more specific as to which culture? There is Athenians, Spartans, Mycenaeans and etc. Each had different cultures and different beliefs.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I will admit, my research has not been very extensive. I'm not particularly knowledgeable in History in general, except maybe a few specific areas, so I wouldn't really know where to start looking for details. Although the google search does show some old looking greek villages, I don't know what era they are from. I would quite like ancient Greece, like maybe 100 BC. I doubt that there are many such villages still standing and in use nowadays. I'd also like to know more about the life of these villages. Do you know some good resources where I can easily look up these things?

Comment: @Neo1009 Good point. I don't really know which one I would like to emulate, because I really don't know enough about these cultures. I guess because I am not going for Greece but really "Ancient Greece Fantasy Land", I would need to integrate the most recognised cultural elements, which is Athens? And probably some Sparta after the 300 movie's popularity. However, it would also be interesting to see some of the differences between these cultures, so that I could base certain regions on different cultures. I already plan on having separate city-states with different cultures :)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right SE for your question.  It might be, but it also might fit really well at the Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I had considered that too, but with this question I am looking for concrete historical evidence concerning life of the Greek "peasantry" in the appropriate time period. Once I have this information, I might visit Worldbuilding SE to stitch it all together into something coherent.